# Why do some websites use www1. rather than www?

Tags: domains, url

Why do some websites use `www1.` rather than `www.`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens that they've enabled [wildcard DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record), and will serve up requests to sub domains named, well anything at all. No, really. Anything at all.

Also... a long time ago, serving up the same content on multiple subdomains named "www#" was a cheap and simple load balancing technique.  Each domain would correspond to a physical server. It fell out of common practice with the advent of sane [reverse proxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) and simplified virtual hosting technologies.

Comment: Is it applicatable to all sites?

Comment: The technique requires two bits of configuration. First, a wildcard DNS entry for the domain, as noted in my first link. Second, it requires server software that can handle arbitrary domain names. The easiest way to accomplish that (that I know of) would be using Apache's VirtualHost directives to set up a "default" virtual domain for a specific IP address. Normally the "default" virtual domain is what you see when there's no other domain configured on the IP address in question, but it can easily be used/abused for this purpose. Because it requires configuration, not all sites can do this.

Answer (score 4):

`www.` and `www1.` are just sub domains and there is no difference between the two.